# Google Sheet how to concat and calculate

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I have created a sheet that generate random math questions. I'm having issue create automated answers.
[google sheet concat not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxcKe.png)

[issue example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp81O.png)

How do I get the result in F6? In another word, how do I get 111 in F6 instead of the math 30+81"?

Comment: Try- `SUM(B6,D6)` or `=E6+D6`.

Comment: it's not sum, there are 4 math operations, + - * / and they come up randomly. The whole page of math is automatically generated.

Comment: IFS options works. However, what I'm looking for is an equivalent to Bash's expr.

Comment: in bash I can do expr 12 + 8 and get an answer 20. I can't find such function in Google sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the sum of the two numbers you must use the SUM() formula in the cell you want it to get the result.
The SUM() formula is used as follows:

> =SUM(number_1,number_2,number_3...)

In your case the formula would be:

> =SUM(B6,D6)

After your comment:
You can use the IFS formula, its a bit tricky but it would work.
The syntaxis is this:

> IFS(condition1, value1, condition2, value2, …)

To do what you want you should implement something like this:

```
=IFS(C6="-"; B6-D6; C6="+"; B6+D6;C6="/"; B6/D6; C6="*"; B6*D6)
```

This formula will check the cell operator and depending on it will perform one action or another.

Comment: =IFS(C9="-", B9-D9, C9="+", B9+D9,C9="*",B9*D9,C9="/",B9/D9)

Answer (score 1):

You may try `QUERY()` function with a helper column, like this-

```
=query(,"Select "&D1&" label "&D1&" ''",0)
```

[image]

Alternatively, without a helper column, the formula would be-

```
=query(,"Select "&A1&B1&C1&" label "&A1&B1&C1&" ''",0)
```

Comment: Thanks Shepherd. Actually I was testing the formula by D column but forgot to remove it and include to query select statement.